# What is the Right Way™ to run a minecraft server?

Tags: 12.04, server, minecraft

I want to run a minecraft server on Ubuntu 12.04 server in a maintainable and secure way.
I know about creating an own user for minecraft to avoid running as root.
I know about using screen to be able to detach from the session without the server stopping.

Still, this all seems like patchwork, as opposed by say... a mysql server that will automatically update when there are security fixes, that will automatically start on boot etc etc.

So, since there are a bunch of servers out there and probably some smart people wanting the same thing, are there any cleaner/more beautiful/more elegant ways of packaging/running a minecraft server on let's say a 12.04 VRoot Server?

I have seen this question:

- [Does running a Minecraft server run with less lag on Ubuntu server than on Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245563/running-minecraft-server-on-ubuntu-server)

This seems very unmaintainable, and if my server reboot for whatever reasons I have to manually start it again. That's why I would prefer something cleaner.

If not, why not? ( <-- this is obviously just to satisfy my curiosity)

Comment: Had seen this question already, but as I wrote, this seems very unmaintainable, and if my server reboot for whatever reasons I have to manually start it again.

That's why I would prefer something cleaner, and the question is how clean it can really get.

Comment: load shell script on boot that updates and launches?